# How can i copy a list of file to a single directory

Tags: linux

I want to copy a list of files into a single directory, but make the target directory the first filename in the command, how can I do it with linux command.

Comment: Is creating a new script an option?

Comment: no just i want do it with 1 command line

Comment: Is this a puzzle?  There are some potentially tricky ways to do it like:  echo target_dir | mv file1 file2 file3 $(cat)

Answer (score 2):

```
dir=$(basename /usr/abc)
for file in a b c d e f
do
  mv $file /usr/abc/${dir}${file}
done
```

Comment: can I  write this without writing script? in one commands

Comment: well, you just glue all the command using `;`

Comment: @ajreal: except between do and mv

Answer (score 1):

`man cp` gives you the -t option:

```
cp -t dir a b c d e f
```